# Sinon stub is not changing the behavior if dependency is already loaded

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

**process.js**

```
const { getConnection, closeConnection } = require('./utils/db-connection.js');

const getQueryCount = query => new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
  getConnection().then((conn) => {
    conn.query(query, (err, count) => {
      closeConnection(conn);
      if (err) {
        log.info(`Get Count Error:  ${err}`);
        return rejects(err);
      }
      return resolve(count[0][1]);
    });
  });
});
```

**process.test.js**

```
const dbConn = require('../src/utils/db-connection.js');
describe('all count', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      sinon.stub(dbConn, 'getConnection').resolves({ query: sinon.stub().yields(null, [[0, 5]]) });
      sinon.stub(dbConn, 'closeConnection');
  const process = require('./src/process'); //module is loaded after dependencies are stubbed

    });

    it('getQueryCount', () => {
      process.getQueryCount('query').then((result) => {
        expect(result).to.equal(5);
      });
    });
  });
```

**In the above scenario stub works but throws Module did not self-register.
And below scenario stub doesn't work.**

**process.test.js**

```
  const dbConn = require('../src/utils/db-connection.js');
      const process = require('./src/process'); // test file is loaded at the starting
    describe('all count', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          sinon.stub(dbConn, 'getConnection').resolves({ query: sinon.stub().yields(null, [[0, 5]]) });
          sinon.stub(dbConn, 'closeConnection');
    
        });
    
        it('getQueryCount', () => {
          process.getQueryCount('query').then((result) => {
            expect(result).to.equal(5);
          });
        });
      });
```

"sinon": "9.0.2"
"mocha": "^3.4.2", //even checked with mocha 7.0.1
node --version
v8.11.3
npm --v
6.2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order stub to work, you need to change the implementation on *process.js*, from using destructuring assignment to normal assignment ([reference](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/)).

`const { getConnection, closeConnection } = require('./utils/db-connection.js');`

for example to

`const db = require('./utils/db-connection.js');`

Complete example:

```js
// Simplified process.js
const db = require('./db-connection.js');

const getQueryCount = (query) => new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
  // Called using db.getConnection.
  db.getConnection().then((conn) => {
    conn.query(query, (err, count) => {
      // Called using db.closeConnection.
      db.closeConnection(conn);
      if (err) {
        return rejects(err);
      }
      return resolve(count[0][1]);
    });
  });
});

module.exports = { getQueryCount };
```

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

// Simple path just for example.
const dbConn = require('./db-connection.js');
const process = require('./process.js');

describe('all count', function () {
  let stubGetConnection;
  let stubCloseConnection;

  beforeEach(function () {
    stubGetConnection = sinon.stub(dbConn, 'getConnection').resolves({ query: sinon.stub().yields(null, [[0, 5]]) });
    stubCloseConnection = sinon.stub(dbConn, 'closeConnection');
  });

  it('getQueryCount', function (done) {
    process.getQueryCount('query').then((result) => {
      expect(result).to.equal(5);
      // Need to verify whether stub get called once.
      expect(stubGetConnection.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
      expect(stubCloseConnection.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
      // Need to notify mocha when it is done.
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

**Note:** I use done there because it is an [asynchronous code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

```
$ npx mocha process.test.js --exit


  all count
    ✓ getQueryCount


  1 passing (17ms)

$
```

Comment: That works. Thanks mate. Now I am think, why I haven't have such thought. I wasted nearly 5 weekends